# How to access the last filename in a directory in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-os, fileparsing

I'm trying to loop through some files in a directory. If the filename has two specific strings together, then I'm supposed to open and read those files for information. However, if none of the files have those two strings, I want to print an error message only once.

```
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
   if filename.find("<string1>") != -1 and filename.find("<string2>") != -1:
      #open file
   else:
      #print error message
```

I know doing this will print as many error messages as there are files in the directory (i.e. if there's 15 files with no matches, I'll get 15 error messages). But what I want is to only print an error message once after there aren't any matches in any of the N files in directory. I figured I could do something like this:

```
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
   if filename.find("<string1>") != -1 and filename.find("<string2>") != -1:
      #open file
   else:
      if filename[-1]: #if filename is last in directory
         #print error message
```

But I've discovered this doesn't work. How would I get an error message to print only after the last filename has been read and doesn't match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution would be to initialize some boolean flag before your for loop, e.g. `found = false`

If you find a file, set `found = true`.  Then you can check the value of `found` after your for loop finishes and print the appropriate message based on its value.

Comment: Thank you! I'm still a novice so I never thought to do this. Worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Filter the list of files before the `for`-loop:

```
filenames = [fname for fname in os.listdir(directory) 
             if '<string1>' in fname and '<string2>' in fname]
if filenames:
    for filename in filenames:
        #open file
else:
    #print error message
```

You can probably also use the `glob` module to get the filenames:

```
import glob
filenames = glob.glob(directory + '/*string1*string2*')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use a variable to check if all the files have been processed. Checked and found it working in Python 2.7

```
import os

directory = "E:\\test\\"
files_count = len(os.listdir(directory))
files_processed = 0
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
   if 'string1' in filename and 'string2' in filename:
      #open file
      print ("Opening file")
   else:
    files_processed = files_processed + 1
    if (files_processed >= files_count):
        print ("error message")
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is extreme. But I'd make it a function and raise IOError.
Plus, i'd always use absolute path. Try the `pathlib` module too

```
import os

def get_files(directory):
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        if "string1" in filename and "string2" in filename:
             yield filename
    raise IOError("No such file")

for file in get_files('.'):
    print(file)
    # do stuff with file
```